# Laravel API - Acceder a archivos de mi servidor mediante una url

Tags: php, laravel, servidor, url

Muy buenas gente,

Hoy tengo la siguiente duda; dispongo de un servidor que en cuanto me conecto como un usuario corriente, lo redirigo a una ruta especifica ( "/front/resources/Timmy/hola.txt" ). Me gustaría que este pudiese ver determinados archivos de mi servidor mediante una url ( **url: "servidor.es/front/resources/$cliente/$nombre_archivo" --> archivo de dentro del servidor: "/web/reporting/client_data/Clients_Reports/$cliente/hola.txt"** ).

Os muestro lo que he hecho hasta el momento:

- Este es **el controlador** que recibe los datos de la url para escoger el cliente y el nombre del archivo ( la ruta del controlador corresponde con la de los clientes ):

  `public function resources($client, $name){`

  ```
      $client1 = str_replace('..', '', $client);
      $name1 = str_replace('..', '', $name);
      $urlComplete = __DIR__ . '../../client_data/Clients_Reports/'.$client1.'/'.$name1;
  ```

  `//Muestra el contenido del archivo:`

  ```
          echo $client." -- ".$name.": ";
          echo "<br>";
          $output = file_get_contents($urlComplete);
          echo $output;

  }
  ```
- Estas son las rutas de interés ( **web.php** ):

  `Route::get('/front/resources/{client}/{name}','FrontController@resources');`
- Y este **el error** que me da:

`file_get_contents(/usr/home/servidor.es/web/reporting/app/Http/Controllers../../client_data/Clients_Reports/Timmy/holi.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Creo que la ruta que me encuentra es errónea ( ya que en local me funcionaba ) y por lo tanto estoy buscando cual es la ruta correcta para que el cliente pueda acceder al archivo de texto en cuestión.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas internautas,

Finalmente he solucionado este problema mediante el código siguiente:

```
        $client1 = str_replace('..', '', $client);
        $name1 = str_replace('..', '', $name);
        $urlComplete = 'ftp://user:password@reporting.server.es/web/reporting/client_data/Clients_Reports/'.$client1.'/'.$name1;

        if(file_exists($urlComplete) == 1){
            include $urlComplete;

        }
        else{
            echo "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.";
            echo "<br>Url: ".$urlComplete;
        }

    }
```

Simplemente he usado el método de "ftp" para llamar al directamente al archivo del servidor y únicamente debemos ejecutar el código php mediante "include nombre_archivo.php". 
Mi error se debía a varios factores: la ruta y la ejecución.

- La ruta: La ruta que especificaba el archivo php, no correspondía con otros archivos que llamaba este mismo y me saltaba otros errores ( file not exists ).
- La ejecución: El código se ejecutaba desde el directorio "public" y yo lo llamaba desde otro directorio, por lo tanto el ftp no correspondía con la url.

**Conclusión:** Ten en cuenta desde donde apunta tu aplicación y reescribe si hace falta el codigo ejecutable tal que así:

```
 $rutafiles = '../client_data/Clients_Reports/nueva_Url';
```

Para que apunte donde debe.

Muchas gracias a todos por responder y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He llegado a mostrar el contenido del txt mediante el uso de "ftp://servidor.es/web/.../hol.txt".

Ahora mi duda es: si quiero ejecutar un archivo php mediante este procedimiento, ¿Como debería ejecutar-lo?

```
echo $client." -- ".$name.": ";
            echo "<br>";
            //$output = file_get_contents($urlComplete);
            //echo $output;
            include $urlComplete;
```

Con esto me dice que tengo el siguiente error:

```
include(): ftp:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

Ya he habilitado el "allow_url_fopen" en mi servidor ( que incluye el "include" ), pero sigue dándome error. ¿Como lo ejecuto entonces?

Comment: Para poder descargar archivos, hace falta una vista , el controlador imprime los datos sobre la vista y te descarga la vista. Podrás ver un ejemplo en "Descargar pdf con Laravel" yo lo hice hace 4 meses.

Comment: Disculpa por mi atrevimiento pero, realicé un "$output = file_get_contents( archivo.php )", luego un echo de "$output" y en local funciona. Luego en el servidor no.

Comment: Una cosa es obtener el nombre y otra obtener el archivo.Mira en youTube como descargar pdf con Laravel, yo lo hice así y sin problemas.

Comment: Pero de que me sirve descargar pdf con Laravel si eso no es lo que quiero hacer? Me gustaría ejecutar dicho php que me funciona en local ( ahora el php se ejecuta pero me da errores que en el local no ).

Comment: Perdón, entendí mal, pensé que en función de un usuario ,descargaba hola.txt o algo de eso. Lo que tienes que hacerte es recoger el contenido en forma de árbol de la ruta que en función del usuario tenga permisos.

Para ejecutar un archivo php externo, sólo tienes que llamar a dicha función de ese php. Yo por ejemplo usaba Ajax ya que desde el propio laravel no era capaz.

Comment: No pasa nada, si estáis para ayudarme ;) lo siento yo que estoy un poquito agobiado. Si, he probado lo que me dices y efectivamente era por la ruta, es decir, el servidor me cargaba el php en "public"; solo tenia que especificar el directorio en el cual quiero que me apunte el php para localizar-lo. Gracias

Comment: Esto lo he visto antes debido a que mi php genera ".jsons" y estos llegaban a crear-se en el directorio public.

Comment: Entonces cuál es ahora tu problema, es que no me queda claro.

Comment: Ninguno, ya lo he solucionado ( tu comentario me ha dado una idea aproximada de la solución en cuestión ). Gracias por todo

Comment: ¿ Podrías autoresponderte ? , para que , si alguien tuviera en un futuro el mismo problema, pudiera ver la solución .

Comment: De acuerdo, pues hasta otra ;)